# Full text search exception with special characters in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, ejb, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to get the list of objects by search text. If I proceed this with special character string for ex,

```
searchText ="Agenya\\&\&";
```

query like this
(I am using Postgres's full text search method)

```sql
select object from Object object where object.Id = :Id and fts('english',object.searchColumn,'Agenya\\&\&') = true  order by object.objectName asc
```

I am getting the exception like this:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleExceptionInOurTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:63)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:83)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:304)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invokeLocal(IsLocalInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessRemoteProxy.invoke(StatelessRemoteProxy.java:107)
    at $Proxy1152.getAllOpportunitiesBySearchText(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the rather dated Postgres 8.4. Default setting for [**`standard_conforming_strings`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) in this version is `off`.

What does this give you?

```sql
SHOW standard_conforming_strings;
```

If you get `off`, backslashes in strings are treated as escape characters. It's not clear to me from the question what's supposed to be an escape character and what should be a literal backslash. Sanitize your strings accordingly.

Double up literal backslashes and prepend the string with `E` so they keep working after the switch. Or switch to `on`. Be sure to read about the consequences first.

Also check if any of your software layers treat `\` as escape character as well. You might have to double up again. If in doubt, log statements with [`log_statement = on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT) in your database log ans check what Postgres actually gets.

Upgrade to a current version of Postgres.

---

Asides:

In Postgres, an expression like:

```sql
fts(...) = true
```

... in the `WHERE` clause can be simplified to just:

```sql
fts(...)
```

[Identifiers are cast to lower case](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) if not double-quoted. Therefore:

```sql
from Object object
```

... is effectively just a noisy way of saying:

```sql
from object
```

See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)